# How to use collection_select with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to use `collection_select` on a form to set a User to a Course.
My many-to-many relation works perfectly but I don't understand what should I put in my `collection_select`.

I have this:

Controller:

```
def create
    @course_user = CoursesUser.new(course_params)
    @course_user.save
    redirect_to :back
end

def course_params
    params.permit(:course_id, :user_id)
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for lecturer_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:course_id, Course.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I set `user_id` with the value for `current_user.id` but I don't know how to set my `course_id`.

Comment: Formatting variables and values in the text is an important part of making a question readable. I'd recommend reviewing other questions and answers to see how we do it, then read the help available when editing, and implement appropriate formatting. It's a readability thing that helps us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function params is 
`collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})`

(taken from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)

in your case you miss the object param, try this:

```
collection_select(@course_user, :course_id, Course.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true)
```

the result should be

```
<select name="courses_user[course_id]" id="courses_user_course_id">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Random Course</option>
  <option value="2">Random Course 2</option>
  <option value="3">Random Course 3</option>
</select>
```

you can read more from the docs on api.rubyonrails.org inside **FormOptionsHelper**

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Actually you were right. Just if you can edit for other peoples with this: `<%= collection_select(@course_user, :course_id, Course.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>` Remove the f. and @course_user as object param ! Thanks again !